# ghost DIV in Google Maps creates clickable shadow

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I have my first web site :), almost ready. 
There are a few little problems that I have spent days with no solution in sight. 
The customized google maps with custimezed google infobubble creates this div that creates a clickable shadow... 
See below the the ghost DIV that I did not create just underneath of the word "cadastro", to the right of the navigation bar:

```
<div id="eccaption_0" class="eccaption" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color: black; color: white; top: 63px; left: 708.328125px; width: 158px; opacity: 0.5;"><p></p></div>
```

Here is the page: [braaasil.com](http://braaasil.com/login.html)
If you cick on cadastro, there is no ghost shadow. If you click on "Sem Fronteiras", you will see the same little ghost. I have learned my way with firebug in the last 7 months or so, but this little problem is kind of surreal... 
It seems to be related to infobubble, but I can't find the source of the problem. It can be "fixed" in the firebug console, but not in the real code... because there is no such div.. Also, I had alt= logo in the img tag and I could se the semi transparent div with the word logo in there. Once I delete the "alt" parameter from img, I get just the skinny div.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFter trying to create a style for the div created by the browser, I finally came up with a solution to shrink it. Not the best solution, but it works.

```
.eccaption { width:0;  
position:fixed !important;
height:0

}
```

This "fix" brought the browser's div/class to the right spot (at the img tag) and the height 0, widht 0 make it disappear.

I will need to fix the other problem raised by the PW Kad, the ad, which I can't see in my desktop, laptop and tablet (not optimized for the tablet yet). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The div is a child element of the following HTML block -

```
<div id="navig" style="position:absolute; top:11px; left:51%">  
    <ul>
        <li id="navigation">
            <a href="index.html">
                <span>
                    <div id="eccaption_0" class="eccaption" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color: black; color: white; top: 63px; left: 708.328125px; width: 158px; opacity: 0.5;">
                    <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/logo1.fw.png" id="ecimage_0">
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Go look in your HTML and you should find it there or something is creating it.

By the way, I am using Chrome and right-clicking and clicking on 'Inspect Element' shows me your HTML, the same thing should work in FireFox.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, I use chrome as well, whatever helps to debug. It's not in the htm... and I've been looking into this problem for a few days now.. can't find the source of the problem. Max I can sa, it's realted to img (but the same ims is in different pages but no problem - no custom google maps either). Img + custom map + custom infobubble seems to be the problem.

Comment: Have you thought about searching for eccaption in your editor?  Something is creating that HTML block, and unless there is indeed a ghost residing on your web server it is indeed in your jQuery, your HTML, whatever other plugins you are using.  For the style to be explicitly stated it is most likely not coming from your CSS

Comment: Yes, I did , and as a matter of fact, I tryied to create a CSStyle to the ghost div. didn't work...

Comment: I don't understand this:"For the style to be explicitly stated it is most likely not coming from your CSS" It's not in the html, it's not in my CSS (it's in google's / browser's CSS/html).

Comment: Do you not see the huge ad that shows up on your login page either?

Comment: Nope! I am still fixing little problems, and I just changed the login page. ** But never saw this ad ! ** And I am using a latop and desktop, I don't see anything. Man... pls tell me more about the add.